# VSCode C/C++ symbols gtags

Tags: c++, open-source, visual-studio-code, configure

Hy,
I am trying to optimize symbol search and access in vscode for c/c++ project.
I've installed c/c++, c/c++ snippets and c++ intellisense extensions and run gtags.
Now for the question, how can i make it automatically run gtags whenever i modify a file or change branch on repository or anything similar to changes?  That is if there is a way other then submitting it as bug/feature request to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ Intellisense refreshes GPATH, GRTAGS and GTAGS when you save a file, so I assume it runs gtags.